# Spring Boot 2 2.3 /2.4 auto shutdown with Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory hikari pool

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring boot 2.3.3 with MySQL 8, InnoDB Engine. I've created few repository interfaces and accessing data in standard way by extending CrudRepository interface. I've been observing a strange issue of my spring boot app get's shutdown after few minutes / hours while it's already running. This happens intermittently and I can see sometime with update entity, while sometime with create and get operation. There's no exception in the log. I can see the latest log as

```
INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean [SpringContextShutdownHook] Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

I've configured hikari as following in my application.yml:

```
spring.datasource:
  url: "jdbc:mysql://myserver:<myport>/mydb"
  username: "<myuser>"
  password: "<mypwd>"
  hikari:
    maximum-pool-size: 20
    minimum-idle: 10
    max-lifetime: 1800000
    idle-timeout: 30000
    pool-name: "MyAppDataSourcePool"
```

I also have following config for hibernate in application.yml

```
spring.jpa:
  show-sql: false
  generate-ddl: false
  hibernate:
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    ddl-auto: none
    naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
    naming:
      physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
  properties:
    hibernate:
      generate_statistics: false
      hbm2ddl.auto: none
```

I've kind of following DB table definition (not the real table) - I'm also suspecting is this due to the unique key I defined will give an issue while saving? Do I need to use composite key instead of unique key for the two fields?

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Reference to Employee',
  `dept_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Reference to Dept',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `my_idx1` (`emp_id`,`dept_id`),
  KEY `FK_1` (`emp_id`),
  KEY `FK_2` (`dept_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`deptid`) REFERENCES `Department` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=769 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='Sample Test Table'
```

I've changed the hikari config several times according to documentation and suggestions from couple forums but still there's no change on behavior. Can someone guide here? Thanks. I've h2 db dependency in my pom.xml with runtime scope, would that be creating an issue? not sure

Comment: 1) Try to remove the following properties:

           max-lifetime: 1800000
           idle-timeout: 30000

    Probably automatic closing of all connection leads to EM Factory Bean shutdown

2) If you use MySQL 8 would it be safer to have:

        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect   ?

Comment: doesn't work removing this property, also tried by adding spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query: "SELECT 1" but nothing works